# API Resources laravel filter data

Tags: php, laravel

So i am trying to get some data pass to an array and send to json. 
But when i do this i am getting alot of information:

This is the response:

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [{
    "id": 2,
    "object_id": 3,
    "booking_id": 1,
    "sender_id": 1,
    "receiver_id": 2,
    "message": "It is accepted",
    "type_id": 5,
    "read": 1,
    "archive": 0,
    "star": 0,
    "created_at": "2019-02-26 11:45:28",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-26 12:15:11",
    "created_time": "26\/02\/2019",
    "host_user": 0,
    "guest_user": 1,
    "sender": {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Joe",
      "last_name": "Cos",
      "email": "email-91@hotmail.com",
      "profile_image": null,
      "balance": 0,
      "status": "Active",
      "created_at": "2019-02-21 15:19:26",
      "updated_at": "2019-02-21 15:19:26",
      "profile_src": "http:\/\/xxx.com\/public\/images\/user_pic-225x225.png"
    },
    "bookings": {
      "id": 1,
      "object_id": 3,
      "code": "mYuL4p",
      "host_id": 1,
      "user_id": 2,
      "start_date": "2019-02-26",
      "end_date": "2019-02-27",
      "status": "Accepted",
      "guest": 0,
      "total_night": 1,
      "per_night": 20,
      "base_price": 20,
      "cleaning_charge": 0,
      "guest_charge": 0,
      "service_charge": 0,
      "security_money": 0,
      "host_fee": 0,
      "total": 20,
      "booking_type": "request",
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "cancellation": "Flexible",
      "transaction_id": "67427302T32774838",
      "payment_method_id": 1,
      "accepted_at": "2019-02-26 11:45:28",
      "expired_at": null,
      "declined_at": null,
      "cancelled_at": null,
      "cancelled_by": null,
      "created_at": "2019-02-26 11:37:36",
      "updated_at": "2019-02-26 11:45:28",
      "host_payout": 23,
      "label_color": "success",
      "date_range": "Feb 26 - 27, 2019",
      "expiration_time": "2019\/02\/27 11:37:36",
      "currency": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Europe",
        "code": "EUR",
        "symbol": "&euro;",
        "rate": "0.88",
        "status": "Active",
        "default": "0",
        "org_symbol": "&euro;"
      }
    },
    "object_address": {
      "id": 3,
      "object_id": 3,
      "address_line_1": "XXXXXXXXX, 4050-352 Porto, Portugal",
      "address_line_2": null,
      "latitude": "49.999",
      "longitude": "-8.88810419921",
      "city": "P",
      "state": "P",
      "country": "P",
      "postal_code": "4050-352"
    }
  }],
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 1,
  "next_page_url": null,
  "per_page": 10,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 1,
  "total": 1
}
```

I am using the API Resources

In MY Resource i have:

```
   return parent::toArray($request);
```

With this i get all that information my problem is i need to filter some data
and when i try to filter for exemple the email.

```
   return [
        'email'=> $this->email,
    ];
```

it gives error and says
"Property [email] does not exist on this collection instance."

I am learning and i am a newbie i am sorry for this dumb questions.
Thanks to all!

Comment: You get the property issue, I suspect, because `email` is a property of `$this->sender`, not `$this` in your response you've shown.

Comment: yes the email is property of sender but how i can say to return the sender->email? The info in on the array i just whant to filter :S and not get all the info

Comment: You'd do `'email' => $this->sender->email` for that.

Answer (score 1):

First make a trait

```
trait ResourceHelpers
{
    /**
     * Remove null values from Eloquent api resource
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function removeNullValues(array $data)
    {
        $filtered_data = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $filtered_data[$key] = $this->when($value !== null, $value);
        }

        return $filtered_data;
    }
}
```

Then use it in your resource

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{

    use ResourceHelpers;

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->removeNullValues([
            "id" => $this->id,
            "first_name" => $this->first_name,
            "last_name" => $this->last_name,
            "phone" => $this->phone,
            "email" => $this->email,
            "balance" => $this->balance,
            'address' => $this->address,
            'city' => $this->city,
            'state' => $this->state,
            'zip_code' => $this->zip_code,
            'country' => CountryResource::make($this->whenLoaded('country')),
            "joined_at" => $this->created_at,
            "updated_at" => $this->updated_at,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your resource:

```
$return = parent::toArray($request);

unset($return['email']);

return $return;
```

Or, you can explicitly define just what you **do** want to return, instead of relying on `toArray`:

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'message' => $this->message,
    // and so on...
];
```

This gives you more control over the final API response, especially if you make database/model changes but need the API to remain unchanged.

Comment: When i try to explicitly say what i want to return it gives error! if i put what you have post it gives Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @FreeLancer You should read the docs on "Resource Collections": https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections